# The "dictionary_term" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition()

Tags: 8, entities

I followed [How to create a custom entity in Drupal 8](https://www.droptica.com/blog/how-create-custom-entity-drupal-8/) to create a module. When I installed it, I got the following error.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "dictionary_term" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

What do I need to change in the following code?

#### dictionary/Entity/Term.php

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\content_entity_example\Entity\ContentEntityExample.
 */

namespace Drupal\dictionary\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;

/**
 * Defines the ContentEntityExample entity.
 *
 * @ingroup dictionary
 *
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 * id = "dictionary_term",
 * label = @Translation("Dictionary Term entity"),
 * handlers = {
 * "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 * "list_builder" = "Drupal\dictionary\Entity\Controller\TermListBuilder",
 * "form" = {
 * "add" = "Drupal\dictionary\Form\TermForm",
 * "edit" = "Drupal\dictionary\Form\TermForm",
 * "delete" = "Drupal\dictionary\Form\TermDeleteForm",
 * },
 * "access" = "Drupal\dictionary\TermAccessControlHandler",
 * },
 * list_cache_contexts = { "user" },
 * base_table = "dictionary_term",
 * admin_permission = "administer dictionary_term entity",
 * entity_keys = {
 * "id" = "id",
 * "uuid" = "uuid",
 * "user_id" = "user_id",
 * "created" = "created",
 * "changed" = "changed",
 * "pl" = "pl",
 * "en" = "en",
 * },
 * links = {
 * "canonical" = "/dictionary_term/{dictionary_term}",
 * "edit-form" = "/dictionary_term/{dictionary_term}/edit",
 * "delete-form" = "/dictionary_term/{dictionary_term}/delete",
 * "collection" = "/dictionary_term/list"
 * },
 * field_ui_base_route = "entity.dictionary.term_settings",
 * )
 */
class Term extends ContentEntityBase {

  use EntityChangedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * When a new entity instance is added, set the user_id entity reference to
   * the current user as the creator of the instance.
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
    parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
// Default author to current user.
    $values += array(
      'user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Define the field properties here.
   *
   * Field name, type and size determine the table structure.
   *
   * In addition, we can define how the field and its content can be manipulated
   * in the GUI. The behaviour of the widgets used can be determined here.
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

// Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the Term entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

// Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
      ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the Contact entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

// Name field for the contact.
// We set display options for the view as well as the form.
// Users with correct privileges can change the view and edit configuration.
    $fields['pl'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Polish'))
      ->setDescription(t('Polish version.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'default_value' => '',
        'max_length' => 255,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -6,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -6,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['en'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('English'))
      ->setDescription(t('English version.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
        'default_value' => '',
        'max_length' => 255,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

// Owner field of the contact.
// Entity reference field, holds the reference to the user object.
// The view shows the user name field of the user.
// The form presents a auto complete field for the user name.
    $fields['user_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('User Name'))
      ->setDescription(t('The Name of the associated user.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'author',
        'weight' => -3,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'settings' => array(
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => 60,
          'placeholder' => '',
        ),
        'weight' => -3,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

    return $fields;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal doesn't find the entity class because the file containing its implementation has been put in the wrong directory. If *dictionary* is the directory containing the module, the *Term.php* file for that entity must be in *dictionary/src/Entity/Term.php*, not *dictionary/Entity/Term.php*. That is what PSR-4 namespaces require, in Drupal 8, as described in [PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8).

> 1. Each module has a namespace that corresponds to its module name.
>    Here: `Drupal\vegetable\`
> 2. The module's namespace is mapped to the ./src/ folder in the module directory.
>    Here: `Drupal\vegetable\` → `modules/vegetable/src/`

Note that the example in that page **doesn't** mean you have to create a *modules* directory inside the directory containing the module. It just shows the parent directory of the directory containing the module (which in the example is *vegetable*). It doesn't even mean the parent directory of the directory containing the module must necessarily be *modules*.

To have a confirm of the correct directory, it's sufficient to see where Drupal core places the files for its entity classes.

- `User` => [core/modules/user/src/Entity/User.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/9.0.x)
- `Node` => [core/modules/node/src/Entity/Node.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/9.0.x)
- `Term` => [core/modules/taxonomy/src/Entity/Term.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/9.0.x)

Leaving out *core/modules*, which is where all Drupal core modules are places, it's clear that, for example, the file containing the `Node` class is placed in the *src/Entity* directory inside the directory containing the *node.module* file.